# Explorer Add-On development

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

I'm developing an add-on to Internet Explorer and I wish to add a button to the standard toolbar. All I could find is how to make my own toolbar.

Any one can point me to the right direction?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588(v=VS.85).aspx) explains how to do it.  Basically you enter some registry keys that tell IE what to do when your button is clicked, as well as some info about the button (text, icon, etc).

Beware: the default location of your button in IE7 and IE8 will probably be in the overflow area of the Command Bar, even if you set `Default Visible` to `yes`.  There is nothing you can do about this.

Also: you can't change the button icon once IE has started, and you can't have a drop-down menu for your button.